# Amazon AWS. IAM user cant upload files "due to errors"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a group with one IAM user. The Group has this policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449507915000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListAllBuckets",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When the user tries to upload a file, he recieves a message that says:

[image]

I tried uploading the same file with the admin user and it works. Thanks for your help, I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: Can you click that triangle next to the error message to get more details? I'm not sure but it looks like you can expand that message.

Comment: I don't get any more deails of the error. If I expand the message, I get a line that writes: `error_aws.jpg` and nothing else.

Comment: And `error_aws.jpg` is just the name of the file I wanted to upload (the image pasted on the question).

Comment: Is there a bucket policy also?

Comment: @James Yes there is one, it grants access to me (the root user I want to delete and the reason I created IAM users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Here's part of your policy:

```
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis"
        ]
```

The problem is you've given broad s3 access **for the bucket**. But you are trying to put a key inside the bucket, which has its own resource. For instance, I added `goat-8.jpg` to your bucket, so it has this arn: `arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis/goat-8.jpg`.

To allow upload to all keys, you can give a wildcard ARN:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis/*"
```

So, putting that in the policy:

```
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis",
            "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis/*"
        ]
```

That will make it *work*. You may choose to get a little more restrictive with the action bits if you don't want your user to delete or doing any shenanigans. Here's an example:

```
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis",
            "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis/*"
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ill test it tommorrow and probably accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found something, but I can't say this is a correct answer. Its just a workaround.

Go to the bucket as admin, then add this permission (the second one):

[image]

I believe this is not a final solution cause it grants permissions to `Any Authenticated User`. Also I truly believe AWS IAM docs are clearly incomplete, they don't mention anything about this bucket-specific permissions. And I can't select the IAM user in the `Grantee` dropdown field, which is confusing.

Comment: yeah, that's a red flag. but hey, now there's a picture of a goat in your s3 bucket. I'll reply after testing.